# Grouping Multidimensional Arrays by Particular Value with nested Standard Class Objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, grouping

In a previous post there was a very helpful answer on grouping multidimensional arrays. My issue is similar with the twist that my initial array has a nested standard class object. My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [InstallationAddress2] => LAKEWOOD, CA  90000
        [LineitemmasterDescription] => Apples
        [Workorder_id] => W008052094
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [InstallationAddress2] => Santa Rosa, CA  90230
        [LineitemmasterDescription] => Berries
        [Workorder_id] => W008022342
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [InstallationAddress2] => LAKEWOOD, CA  90000
        [LineitemmasterDescription] => Apples
        [Workorder_id] => W008052094
    )
)
```

Like the previous post I'm hoping to get something like

```
Array
(
   Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
        [InstallationAddress2] => LAKEWOOD, CA  90000
        [LineitemmasterDescription] => Apples
        [Workorder_id] => W008052094
       )

    [1] => Array
      (
        [InstallationAddress2] => LAKEWOOD, CA  90000
        [LineitemmasterDescription] => Apples
        [Workorder_id] => W008052094
      )
   )
   Array (
     [2] => Array
    (
        [InstallationAddress2] => Santa Rosa, CA  90230
        [LineitemmasterDescription] => Berries
        [Workorder_id] => W008022342
    )
   )
)
```

The thing I'm stumbling over is the standard class object which refuses to be cast into an array.

Comment: How does it refuse to be cast to an array?  How are you trying to cast it?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily cast an stdClass to an array ...

```
$a = array (
    'index_0' => 'value_0',
    'index_1' => 'value_1'
);

$obj = (object) $a;
// Now $obj is an instance of stdClass
$arr = (array) $obj;
// Now it's an array again :)
```

The more-interesting question: Where did you get this array?